# selected value is not showing in edit mode on select2 bootstrap jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two html pages in that i am designed drop down.

I am getting values successfully in dropdown. I selected one value after i saved the page. It is saved successfully. After i am editing the page in that page i am trying to show same drop down with selected value but it not working

```
<form>  
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="empcode" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> Code </label>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 <select class="form-control select2" id="empcode" ></select>
  </div>
</div>
</form> 

$( ".select2" ).select2( );
 var $selectcode = $('#empcode');                               
$.getJSON('/empCodes', function(data1){                            
$selectcode.html('');
$selectcode.append('<option>'+"--Select--"+'</option>');
$.each(data1.data, function(key, val){
$selectcode.append('<option id='+val.id+'>'+val.code+'</option>');
})
});
```

Edit page code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="empcode" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> Code </label>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 <select class="form-control select2" id="empcode" th:value="*{code}">
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

By using `thymeleaf` `th:value="*{code}"` i am showing the selected value.But not working.

Any mistakes in my code?

Comment: is there any error on console ?

Comment: @Ismail Farooq: there is no error in console

Answer (score 1):

Jquery didn't have `select2` method.Check your first line code.

```
$( ".select2" ).select();
```

Could you explain accurately?What's function not work?

Did you want to set selected word to your `label`?If answer is yes,I could donate the simple code for you.

**code**

```
$selectcode.on("change",function(){
  var selectedWord =    $( "#empcode option:selected" ).text();
  $(".control-label").text(selectedWord);
})
```

Comment: No not label, select box only

Answer (score 0):

here your mistake in selector

change this `var $selectcode = $('empcode');` to `var $selectcode = $('#empcode');`

The element selector should have `#` if you selecting element by ID.

So `$('empcode')` should be like this `$('#empcode')`;

Second call the library function after each done / data append.

For example

```
var $selectcode = $('#empcode');
$.getJSON('/empCodes', function(data1) {
    $selectcode.html('');
    $selectcode.append('<option>' + "--Select--" + '</option>');
    $.each(data1.data, function(key, val) {
        $selectcode.append('<option id=' + val.id + '>' + val.code + '</option>');
    });
    // function here 
    $(".select2").select2();
});
```

Comment: I changed but no difference.

Comment: `{"data":[{"id":1,"code":"123"},{"id":2,"code":"456"},{"id":3,"code":"789"},{"id":4,"code":"556"},{"id"
:5,"code":"446"}]}`

Comment: here my problem is 123 is selected for example,okay. I am saved the form with 123. next i am editing the form in this time another html page is called . in this page i am trying to show in drop down default show the 123.

Comment: ah than you need to parse selected value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142799/discussion-between-durga-and-ismail-farooq).